# How to write static recursive method in Java?

Tags: java, string, recursion, methods, static

I want to write codes using a static recursive method in Java, cleanString(String s) that accepts a string of letters s and returns a string where adjacent letters that are the same are replaced by a single occurrence of that letter. The method is case-sensitive.

For example:

```
cleanString("sensssaatiionnaallll!") -> "sensational!"                             

cleanString("PPProoggggraamm") -> "Program"

cleanString("Lletterriiing") -> "Lletering"
```

Comment: What have you done so far ? This would help us comment on what improvements you can do to the code to achieve your results

Comment: How did you arrive to the decision of making a recursive function for solving this problem? Is this your homework?

Comment: Do you mean `void cleanString(String s)` or `String cleanString(String)`?

Comment: and how you will clear "Gooooogle" ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(cleanString("sensssaatiionnaallll!"));
    }
    static String cleanString(String input)
    {
        if(input.length()<1) //To stop infinite recursion
            return input;
        var first = input.charAt(0);
        var count = input.chars().takeWhile(x -> x == first).count();
        return first + cleanString(input.substring((int)count));
    }
}
```

- First, it checks if the length of the string is less than 1. If it is, return the string itself (which is empty) and stop the recursion.
- Next get the first character of the string. (e.g `PPProoggggraamm -> P`)
- Get the number of characters in the start that equal the first character (3 in the case of `PPProoggggraamm`)
- Call the function again, but this time lopping off the first n characters from the above step, and prepending the first character. (`'P' + cleanString("rooggggraamm")`)

Answer (score 0):

It just generate a new String and exclude the repeat characters.

```java
static String cleanString(String input) {
  if(input == null) return null;

  char lastChar = 0;
  StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder(input.length());
  for (int i=0,n=input.length(); i<n; i++) {
    char c = input.charAt(i);
    if(c != lastChar) {
      lastChar = c;
      output.append(c);
    }
  }

  return output.toString();
}
```

Recursive method:

```java
public class Example {
  public static int main(String[] args) {
    String input = "sensssaatiionnaallll";
    String output = cleanString(input, 0);
    System.out.println(output); // print: sensational
    return 0;
  }

  private static String cleanString(String input, int index) {
    if(input == null) return "";
        if(index >= input.length()) return "";

        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

        char current = input.charAt(index);

        int nextIndex = index + 1;
        if(nextIndex >= input.length()) {
            return output.append(current).toString();
        }

        char next = input.charAt(nextIndex);

        if (current != next) {
            output.append(current);
        }

        output.append(cleanString(input, nextIndex));

        return output.toString();
  }
}
```

Comment: Can this code be called as a function inside main method?

Comment: This isn't recursive

Comment: Sorry, I have a mistake and I couldn't noticed that needs a recursive method. I've added a recursive method in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Shortest recursive code to remove adjacent characters from the input string.

```
public class StackOverflow { 

static String cleanString(String input) {
    return input==null || input.length()<=1?input:cleanStringWrapper(input.substring(1),input.substring(0,1));
}

static String cleanStringWrapper(String input, String result) {
  if (input.length() - 1 <= 0) {
    return result+(result.charAt(result.length() - 1)!=input.charAt(0)?input:"");
} else {
    return cleanStringWrapper(input.substring(1), result+(result.charAt(result.length() - 1) != input.charAt(0)?input.charAt(0):""));
}
} 

 public static void main(String[] args) 
 {
     System.out.println(cleanString("OOPS"));
     } 
 }
```

**Output:**

cleanString("sensssaatiionnaallll!") -> "sensational!"

cleanString("PPProoggggraamm") -> "Program"

cleanString("Lletterriiing") -> "Lletering"

cleanString("Gooooogle") -> "Gogle"

cleanString("ABC") -> "ABC"

cleanString("A") -> "A"

cleanString("") -> ""

cleanString(*null*) -> *null*

Comment: Hi, may I know where do you implement this code?
How do I put it in the main function??

Comment: Hello, I have shared updated code with the main class. Please go through once. If you find some difficulty further then we can discuss.

Comment: Alright, it is working! Appreciated your efforts (:

Answer (score -2):

Why you want to make static method for that?

Whay i understood is that you want to remove repeated characters from your input string.

You can do it below code as well.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
str.chars().distinct().forEach(c -> sb.append((char) c));
```

If you want you can make a method of this 2 lines as a feature in your code.

Hope this helps!

Comment: He wants runs of repeated characters to be reduced, not just distinct characters.

Comment: you're very sharp!